# Does any Moderizr property can tell whether browser support grid layout?

Tags: modernizr

everyone! I recently find Grid is a perfect layout style, but browsers like Chrome or FireFox don't support it unless you do some flag settings.
    So if I want to make a grid layout i must detect whether the browser support grid or not. If browser doesn't support it i will load css-grid-polyfill.js and implement it:

```
if (!Modernizr.**some_property**) {
    require(["css-grid-polyfill.js"], function (){
        console.log('css-grid-polyfill.js is loaded');
    });
}
So the problem is what property of the Modernizr can tell whether browser support grid layout or not? Many thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Do you mean flexbox? If so its Modernizr.flexbox

Comment: You can safely say that pretty much no browser [supports grid layout](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid). You don't need Modernizr to tell you that ;)

Comment: @user2693928   "display: grid;" not the flexbox.

Comment: @giorgio  You are right! I check it out, thanks!